# Grab from one HTML5 canvas and draw to another

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas

I am trying to take pixel information from one canvas element, manipulate it, and draw it to another canvas element. I have been able to make this work when I take and draw to the same canvas. It also works in a particular order, but not the order I need.

The idea is to have hidden canvases holding image information which I can pull pixels from, manipulate, then draw to the main canvas. This works when I draw from myCanvas to myCanvas2, but not the other way around. The image I am getting data from does not need to be a canvas, in fact I would prefer if it wasn't as I want as few resources used as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="800" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://timsterrible.net/gaming/pixelsweeper/images/bariumStrip.png';

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(10,10,50,50);

var canRaw = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var canvas = canRaw.getContext("2d");

image.onload = canvas.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

function copy()
{
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(32,0,32,32);
canvas.putImageData(imgData,10,70);
}
</script>

<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>

</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to fade one chemical spill into another when they mix. Right now they are very solid, something you can see when you [play around here](http://timsterrible.net/gaming/pixelsweeper/stack/pixelsweeper.html).

Thanks for any help you can offer with this confounding annoyance.

http://timsterrible.net/gaming/pixelsweeper/stack/notmixing.png

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Are you looking for [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Compositing) or `globalAlpha`?

Comment: Both globalAlpha and globalCompositeOperation are very useful tools. However, I have to do the image data manipulation by hand since neither tool gradients from one image to another. Luckily that's not the issue. The problem I'm having, and ultimately the question is; why can I gather image data from one canvas, but not the other?

Comment: check this answer may b it is useful [stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873374/can-we-drag-and-drop-composite-shapes-from-one-canvas-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following may provide some help in solving your problem.
Add the function getPixel, as a method, to a canvas that is used to contain required images to extract data from.
Add the function putPixel, as a method, to a canvas that is used to contain the final combined image.

I have added a quick test of the functions to see if centre parts of the two images [summer.jpg](https://ed72560c-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/jkgadgetstore/rolocu/summer.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7cow1whv64AcTzv7iR90s3PY1cTzUdT1FTQ5OKVCT_aOeEKvwYVqjPBVFuA2Sv9bA6HkhnqL2lDeow7HhxE9-1u-Nu0zvLJjk8dhtjKY4O8SAkNFvYQyskqeqzm3YmY_03Hk7nyAsrbghrBJIFM4P5DgvQtnhGslx1kFot99kjy6O3kd8cqaLaPOLaUrJiGN0Be7pMshMAp__t74gV8qJyHXkLQlVg%3D%3D&attredirects=0) and [winter.jpg](https://ed72560c-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/jkgadgetstore/rolocu/winter.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7cqTSByJ3xaLV35ooyqG1cdXtNrjD5zLmkvM83vUf7Ixv_y_aY8hjRK8YoxHO-zcAzViPgIbcgliWHKy83D49117Psqw1U2Vzmp2oWZn-VxHCwDKLRePfcI0o4wMZFGXcHXZTJ7fHcQXNxp63kUvMT-GkJ6xH8RzzZMNs2148p_tzDyGWIvz21Ppi1gM4gNwsKYVUl-ABAPWiEIzdFn3_cHi90kSsw%3D%3D&attredirects=0) are correctly combined.

Limitations of the code below is that canvases and images are all to have same widths and heights but that could be easily changed.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>pixel swap</title>
<style type="text/css">
    div, canvas, img {
        position: absolute;
    }

    img {
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        visibility:hidden;
    }

    #imagedata {
        left:10px;
        top:10px;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    #maincanvas {
        left:10px;
        top:10px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // abbreviation function for getElementById
    function $(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    //height and width for all canvases and images
    var W=100;
    var H=100;

    //variables for canvases
    var cid, cmain;


    /*getPixel gets an individual pixel from the image, img
     */
    function getPixel(x,y,img) {
        this.ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        var imdata=this.ctx.getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height);
        var col=4*(y*this.width+x);
        var pix=new Pixel();
        pix.red=imdata.data[col++];
        pix.green=imdata.data[col++];
        pix.blue=imdata.data[col++];
        pix.alpha=imdata.data[col];
        return pix;
    }

    //Pixel Object
    function Pixel() {
        this.red;
        this.green;
        this.blue;
        this.alpha;
    }

    function putPixel(x,y,pixel){
        var imdata=this.ctx.getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height);
        var col=4*(y*this.width+x);
        imdata.data[col++]=pixel.red;
        imdata.data[col++]=pixel.green;
        imdata.data[col++]=pixel.blue;
        imdata.data[col]=pixel.alpha;
        this.ctx.putImageData(imdata,0,0);
    }


    function main() {
        //set cid so that pixels are readable
        cid=$("imagedata");
        cid.width=W;
        cid.height=H;
        cid.ctx=cid.getContext('2d');
        cid.getPixel=getPixel;

        //set cmain so that pixels are settable to main canvas
        cmain=$("maincanvas");
        cmain.width=W;
        cmain.height=H;
        cmain.ctx=cmain.getContext('2d');
        cmain.putPixel=putPixel;

        var img; //image read from
        var pixel;//pixel data

        //testing getPixel and putPixel
        //should be alternating columns in the centre of the combined image in cmain canvas
        for(var x=30;x<70;x++) {
            for(var y=30;y<70;y++) {
                if(x%2==0) {
                    img=$("s")
                }
                else
                {
                    img=$("w")
                }
                pixel=cid.getPixel(x,y,img);
                cmain.putPixel(x,y,pixel);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
    <!-- list of hidden images for reading data-->
    <img id="s" src="images/summer.jpg">
    <img id="w" src="images/winter.jpg">
    <!-- end of list of images  -->

    <canvas id="imagedata"></canvas>
    <canvas id="maincanvas"></canvas>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having trouble with your code. I have tried several variations, used the console log, etc. The conclusion is my computer absolutely hates the getImageData function.

I am going to try some workarounds including saving the images I want to manipulate as 32-bit bitmaps and saving its numerical values into a text document. I would then create the image data pixel-by-pixel when the script begins and just store the data in a ready to use array.

Comment: Apparently there are [security issues surround getimagedata](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules). The code above seems to work OK on my local computer provided the images are as stated. If I replace the src with a link to their url reference on the web it no longer works. Did you download the images or link directly to them?

Comment: I saw they were downloads so I decided I might as well just quickly make my own scribbles in MS Paint, then ran the code locally. I ran this same code on my wife's laptop and it works great. This tells me that just like anything else, not all computers do everything.

I converted my images to bitmaps and extracted the pixel data to be read from a text file. That works well.

Comment: I tried running the program again, now it works! It turns out I missed the whole part about the security flagging files saved on the hard-drive. When I tested on my wife's computer it was online, this is why it worked.

Using a hidden canvas to hold the image is by far better than my workaround of using a text file.